# custom Swing components that resize dynamically but interoperate with LayoutManagers

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a subclassed `JPanel` that acts as a view for some information.

When the information changes, the min/max/preferred size of the `JPanel` may change as well.

How do I handle this event properly so that it plays nicely with a `LayoutManager`?

I tried overriding `getPreferredSize()` but it only seems to be called once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try revalidate your component after min/max/preferred size has been changed. Should work.

Comment: cool, thanks! just to clarify, you mean `Component.revalidate()`? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29

Comment: No, it should just be revalidate(). Your sub class should have methods that change properties of your class. Whenever one of these properties changes that potentially affects the size of the component you invoke revalidate() and repaint(). Look at the source code for other Swing components. Say a JLabel and look at the setText() or setIcon() methods to see how this is done.

Comment: @camickr: I haven't understood your comment. Is my answer wrong?

Comment: You should not use code like component.setPreferredSize(...), component.revalidate(). Instead you should override the class and implement the getPreferredSize() method. In may example above if you use label.setText("abc"), the setText() method is responsible for invoking the revalidate() method. You don't do label.setText(...), label.revalidate().

Comment: @camickr: ah ok. now it's clear. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @0verbose and for compound JComponets sometimes required repaint() +1

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this, just saved me a whole lot of trouble with a custom component I've been working on.